# How to round a floating-point to the nearest .001

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86, rounding

Can someone give me some tips on how to round a floating-point to the nearest .001 in Assembly (MASM)?  I have 2 integers.  I need to show the quotient as a floating-point number (num_1 / num_2).  I got the floating point arithmetic part working, but I couldn't figure out how to round the result.  Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

```
;calculate the quotient as a floating-point number
    fild    num_1
    fidiv   num_2
    roundps

    ;display the quotient as a floating-point number        
    call    WriteFloat
    call    CrLf
```

Comment: For clarification you are talking about the number in base 10, 0.001, with base 2 based floating point numbers, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the number by 1000, round it and then scale back.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 1000 (`fmul`), round to integer (`frndint`), then divide by 1000 (`fdiv`).

The `roundps` instruction requires SSE4.1 and only works with SSE or AVX registers, not the FPU's registers.